# MS Excel - Lookup Cube Dimension Name using Cube Dimension ID; Is it possible?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, mdx, olap, cube

Is it possible in Microsoft Excel 2016, by just using excel formulas, build a formula using the Cube formulas to lookup a value in a cube based on an input provided by the user.

For Example:
Table in the Cube looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWWIj.jpg)

I would like to be able to input the customer ID in Cell E1 and in F1 return the name of the customer who is related to that id, in this instance it would be Link.

I know I could use VBA, and VLookup's by bring in the pivot table, but I am trying to do this using CUBE formulas only. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=CUBEMEMBERPROPERTY("Cube Connection",CUBEMEMBER("Cube Connection","[Customer Table].[Customer ID].["&G8&"]"),"Customer Name")

The answer is the above excel function. Just be aware, that IT has to setup the cube properly. They need to setup the field as a property on the cube itself.

Here is also a working video of the CubeMemberProperty Function: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9pcMa2GwJ8

Comment: It's at 6'08 in the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9pcMa2GwJ8&t=366

For some reason Cubembemberproperty is under-documented and doesn't have intellisense autocomplete. You have to enter the property between quotes and make sure you don't misspell it.

Answer (score 0):

After fumbling around, I found that Cubememberproperty is an MDX function that is NOT supported in PowerPivot. This page has a workaround using the Exists function:
https://wessexbi.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/a-cubememberproperty-equivalent-with-powerpivot/